# An easy way to get the sunset / sunrise times for a city in PHP

Tags: php

Is there a way to get sunrise and sunset times in PHP without having to deal with Zenith and GMT offsets?

The functions `date_sunrise()` and `date_sun()` asks for zenith and GMT which I don't want to deal with.

Ideally I would simply write `someSunriseFunction(<latitude>, <longitude>, <timezone>)`
i.e. `someSunriseFunction(34.30, -118.15, 'EST')` would be for Los Angeles.

Thanks.

Comment: Sunrise happens in different time for different days. What your function should return?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *timezone* is pretty useless for this function. That information is already included in the latitude and longitude. What you need is the location and a *timestamp*, because the sun sets and rises at different times at different times of the year.

And that's exactly what [`date_sun_info`](http://php.net/date_sun_info) gives you:

```
date_sun_info ( int $time , float $latitude , float $longitude )
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to get the sunrise and sunset using the above. There is alot that goes into the calculation. The full Calculation can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_equation#Complete_calculation_on_Earth

If it may be easier give the user a list of citys with predefined values for Zenith, GMT,  LAtitude and Longitude. This can either be some flat file, object, or database driven.

I have used this and used a script to offset for Daylight Savings Time

Comment: deceze does give a good alternative that will work if your PHP version is greater than or equal to 5.1.2. Which most servers should be at this point.